# How to show html form using shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show html form using shortcode. Here is my code:

```
add_shortcode('sms_order_form', 'sms_order_form_html');

function sms_order_form_html(){?>
'<form>
    <div class="tooltip">
        0<input type="range" id="range" value="0" min="0" max="100"/>100
        <span class="tooltiptext">0</span>
    </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

But this doesn't print the form. but if I replace the HTML form by `echo 'hello';` it prints hello. Is there any way to show any HTML using shortcode.

N.B.: shortcode is placed using elementor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcode should return a string:

```
<?php
add_shortcode( 'sms_order_form', 'sms_order_form_html' );

function sms_order_form_html() {
    ob_start();

    ?>
    <form>
        <div class="tooltip">
            0<input type="range" id="range" value="0" min="0" max="100"/>100
            <span class="tooltiptext">0</span>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: I just put the shortcode in elementor. ref: https://prnt.sc/t9weuz

Comment: You are doing something wrong, it works: https://monosnap.com/file/szDtDX7liKdcrJRwA4U8cU9hqtFOlK It looks like that you put code in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks, man! There was a CSS issue that hide the form :( this simple issue kills my couple of hours. Your comment inspires me to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode functions need to return the output in form of a string as opposed to outputting HTML right away. You can use output buffering to return your code like so:

```
add_shortcode('sms_order_form', 'sms_order_form_html');

function sms_order_form_html() {
  ob_start();
?>
<form>
    <div class="tooltip">
        0<input type="range" id="range" value="0" min="0" max="100"/>100
        <span class="tooltiptext">0</span>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
  return ob_get_clean(); // clear the output buffer, and return as string
}
```